# How to disabled a button when a core data variable changes in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to disable a button based on a computed property from the View Model, but is only disabled after the view is reloaded.

This is the View Model :

```
  class VerifyFieldViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    func isValidFirstName() -> Bool {
        guard coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName?.count ?? 0 > 0 else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    func isValidLastName() -> Bool {
        guard coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.lastName?.count ?? 0 > 0 else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    var isFirstNameValid : String {
        if isValidFirstName() {
       return ""
        } else {
        return "Name is empty"
        }
    }
    
    var isLastNameValid : String {
        if isValidLastName() {
       return ""
        } else {
        return "Surname is empty"
        }
    }
    
   var isSignUpComplete: Bool {
        if !isValidFirstName() || !isValidLastName() {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    }
```

This is how I am disabling the button .

```
struct CartsView: View {
    @State var onboardingState: Int = 0
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var verifyFieldViewModel = VerifyFieldViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch onboardingState {

            case 0 :
                VStack {
                detailOrder
                    .transition(transition)
                Spacer()
                bottomButton
                    .padding(30)
                }
            case 1 :
                VStack {
                detailOrder2. -> This is LivrareView
                    .transition(transition)
                    Spacer()
                    bottomButton
                        .padding(30)
                        .opacity(verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpComplete ? 1 : 0.6)
                        .disabled(!verifyFieldViewModel.isSignUpComplete)
                }
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
}
}
```

This is the Core Data View Model :

```
class CoreDataViewModel  : ObservableObject {
    let manager = CoreDataManager.instance
    @Published var savedDetails : [Details] = []
    init() {
        fetchSavedDetails()
    }
    func fetchSavedDetails() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Details>(entityName: "Details")
        do {
            savedDetails = try manager.context.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    
    func saveContext() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.manager.save()
            self.fetchSavedDetails()
        }
        }

}
```

```
struct LivrareView: View {
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @ObservedObject var verifyFieldsViewModel = VerifyFieldsViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        let firstName = Binding(
            get: {coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName ?? ""},
            set: {coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.firstName = $0})
        
        let lastName = Binding(
            get: {coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.lastName ?? ""},
            set: {coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.lastName = $0})
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("First Name")
                    .padding(.top)
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
                EntryField(placeHolder: "Name", prompt: $verifyFieldsViewModel.isFirstNameValid, field: firstName)
                    .onSubmit {
                        coreDataViewModel.saveContext()
                    }
                Text("Last Name")
                    .padding(.top)
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
                EntryField(placeHolder: "Last Name", prompt: $verifyFieldsViewModel.isLastNameValid, field: lastName)
                
                    .onSubmit {
                        coreDataViewModel.saveContext()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE : It works, but only when the view is reloaded.

How can i make this work?. I've tried

Comment: Nested ObservableObjects don't work without manually sending `objectWillChange.send()`. Not only that, but a `@Published` array of CoreData entities (which are themselves `ObservableObject`) won't work either, because `@Published` arrays depend on value types (structs), not reference types to transmit updates properly. Rather than a simple fix (which may not exist in this case) I'd suggest some significant re-architecture with these things in mind.

Comment: Observe the object by wrapping it in `@ObservedObject` then use `yourObject.hasChanges`

Comment: what object do i need to make @ObservedObject and where i needd to use  "yourObject.hasChanges" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of those view models. Just use [`@FetchRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject) in the View that contains the List and [`@ObservedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject) in the Detail View. You can bind the TextField directly to the managed object like `TextField($myObject.firstName)`. Starting with Xcode's app template with the Core Data box ticked is a good way to learn how it works with SwiftUI.